# Gpu image photo app crash

Tags: iphone, ios, gpuimage

I am using GPU image open source framework for image effects. The problem is when i am trying to apply filters regularly on an image the app gives me a memory warning and then crashes.

Here is the code:

```
sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[self scaleAndRotateImage:sourceImage] smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];

GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter *bright=[[GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter alloc]init];
[bright setBlurSize:1.0];

GPUImageFilter *sepiaFilter = bright;
[bright release];
[sepiaFilter prepareForImageCapture];
[sepiaFilter forceProcessingAtSize:self.m_imageView.image.size]; // This is now needed to make the filter run at the smaller output size
[sourcePicture addTarget:sepiaFilter];
[sourcePicture processImage];

UIImage *sep=[sepiaFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
self.m_imageView.image=sep;
[sourcePicture release];
[sepiaFilter release];
```

Please help me to get rid of this problem. Thanks

Comment: Please post the crash log. Without it it's very hard to know what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`sepiaFilter` is not retaining `bright` so it's only going to be a pointer to a released object. You should change it so that it retains the object.

```
GPUImageFilter *sepiaFilter = [bright retain]; // Now retain count is increased +1
```

Otherwise this is what is happening to that object.

```
GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter *bright = [[GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter alloc] init]; // New object with retain count 1
[bright setBlurSize:1.0];

GPUImageFilter *sepiaFilter = bright; // Still retain count 1 (not being retained)
[bright release]; // Being released. Retain count = 0.
// At this point both sephiaFilter and bright point to released memory.

[sepiaFilter prepareForImageCapture]; // This is calling messages on a released object.
[sepiaFilter forceProcessingAtSize:self.m_imageView.image.size]; // This is calling messages on a released object.
[sourcePicture addTarget:sepiaFilter]; // This is passing a released object as an argument.
```

Comment: This might not be the problem. As i am using this code for image processing [sepiaFilter forceProcessingAtSize:self.m_imageView.image.size]; Here if i process image at smaller size say(CGSizeMake(120,120)) it is not giving me a crash. but it affects the image quality during save. So what to do with that?

Comment: I warned about this exact crash in the comments of the answer where they copied all of the above code from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14023316/19679 . Sigh.